# Peewee get all descendants

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, peewee

I am using peewee as a ORM in python (in combination with postgresql) and I am trying to query every descendant of a given id out of a table with self referencing (parent-child)

What is the best way to achieve this?

Edit:

I already setup the peewee model class:

```
class Customer(BaseModel):
    customerid = PrimaryKeyField()
    name = CharField(null=False)
    parentid = ForeignKeyField(db_column='parentid',
                           null=True,
                           rel_model='self', to_field='customerid')
    customer_type_customertypeid = ForeignKeyField(
        db_column='customer_type_customertypeid',
        null=False,
        rel_model=CustomerType, to_field='customertypeid')

class Meta:
    db_table = 'customer'
```

Now I want to query every child of a given customer by id and convert that to a dict

```
C1 = dbhandler.Customer.alias()

try:
    return [model_to_dict(model) for model in
        C1.select().where(...)]
except:
     return {}
```

But I can't think of a query that would achieve this without using a CTE. But since peewee doesn't have support for CTE's I am out of ideas.
I did see that peewee has a .raw(..) function, in which you can put real sql queries, but that would just destroy the advantage of using an ORM.

Comment: The best way is to follow their documentation and "How to get started" rather than asking us to code this for you. I am by no means trying to offend you, it's just that these things pop up very frequently where users haven't tried anything or can't show us what they've tried. Meaning we have no actual code to help you with except code the entire solution for you (which, you might not think you're asking of us.. But it is what you're asking of us). Please show us some effort in trying to solve this, a [Minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Welcome to SO!

Comment: @Torxed I added some actual code

Comment: Much better, close vote retracted. This looks like a legit and good question where someone with better understanding of Peewee (appears to be a new trend) could help out. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to execute a recursive common table expression. Peewee 2.x does not support this yet, but it is in the 3.0 which is currently unreleased as it's got a lot of changes and I haven't finalized some of the APIs. Sorry! Trying to get that out.

Anyways, you can use MyModel.raw('WITH ... ') to run a recursive CTE and receive model instances.

Comment: Great to hear that it will be a feature in the new upcoming release!